# tryCatch results in the same output regardless of error in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write an error exception handling in R using tryCatch.

```
correct = 1
tryCatch({
    sqrt(b)

    },
    warning = function(w){
        print("NaNs")
    },
    finally = {
        correct = 0
    }
)
correct
```

If I set b = -5, the warning is printed and the value of correct is 0. If I set b = 5, the warning is not printed. However the value is still 0. What I would like is that when there is some warning/error to catch, the value of correct is 0. When there is no warning/error, the value of correct is 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `finally` here. Instead just specify return values of 0 when an error or warning occurs.

```
myfun <- function(b) {
    tryCatch({
        sqrt(b)
    },
    error = function(e){
        return(0)
    },
    warning = function(w){
        return(0)
    }
    )
}

> myfun(5)
# [1] 2.236068
> myfun(-5)
# [1] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function:

```
is.bad <- function(x) {
    as.numeric(isTRUE(tryCatch(x,
        error = function(c) TRUE,
        warning = function(c) TRUE
    )))
}

is.bad(stop())
is.bad(warning())
is.bad(message())
is.bad(3)

## > is.bad(stop())
## [1] 1
## > is.bad(warning())
## [1] 1
## > is.bad(message())
## 
## [1] 0
## > is.bad(3)
## [1] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `finally` clause is executed regardless of whether or not a warning is thrown in the square root. That's why you end up with `correct == 0` regardless.

The following code will do what you want, although I used a global assignment `<<-` which might cause problems if you are not careful. This was necessary because otherwise you can't change the value of `correct` from within the `warning` function.

```
correct = 1
tryCatch({
  sqrt(b)      
},
warning = function(w){
  print("NaNs")
  correct <<- 0
}
)
```